# How to put a symbol on the axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to put a symbol on the axes in the form of the
[graph]

[image]

Does anyone know how can I do it in python? Not necessarily both axes at the same time, I just need to know how to do that. i tried with

`ax.set_xticklabels([r'$alpha$'])`

But it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What didn't work? The character didn't *render* or it didn't appear where you wanted it? [https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html)

Comment: No, the character appears, but when I put it the other tags disappear.
In the same way someone gave me a code that works well. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

time = np.arange(0, 12, 0.1);
amplitude = np.sin(time)
plot.plot(time, amplitude,'--')

xrange=list(np.arange(0,13,2))
plot.xticks(xrange+[6.9],xrange+[r'$ \alpha $'])

yrange=list(np.arange(-1,1.5,.5))
plot.yticks(yrange+[0.6],yrange+[r'$ \alpha $'])

plot.title('Sine wave')
plot.xlabel('Time')
plot.ylabel('Amplitude')

plot.grid(True, which='both')
plot.show()
```

which will give you an output
[image]

The output is not exactly the same. if you have to turn off the grid then you have to use cursers or some other method to point out the alpha intersection

Comment: Thank you! It was very useful

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead. It should fix your alpha sign.
I just put 6.4 and 0.6 for the locations.

```
ax.set_xticks([6.4]) 
ax.set_xticklabels([r'$ \alpha $']) 

ax.set_yticks([0.6]) 
ax.set_yticklabels([r'$ \alpha $'])
```

Comment: Yeah, but the other indexes dissapear

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the location and label...  that is ticks and label both..

Plt.xticks(ticks=[1],label=['hi'])

This will print hi at location 1
But then you will not see other indexs... So you have to specify then as well along with it